# M2crypto signature "algorithm"

Tags: python, digital-signature, m2crypto

These two codes provide the same signature, which is expected:

code1:

```
from M2Crypto import RSA, EVP
import base64, hashlib

text = "some text"

pkey = EVP.load_key("mykey.pem")  #"mykey.pem" was generated as: openssl genrsa -des3 -out mykey.pem 2048
pkey.sign_init()
pkey.sign_update(text)
signature = pkey.sign_final()
print base64.b64encode(signature)
```

code2:

```
pkey = RSA.load_key("mykey.pem")
signature = pkey.sign(hashlib.sha1(text).digest())
print base64.b64encode(signature)
```

However, if I want to "imitate" the signature algorithm, i.e. encrypting the digest with the private key, I get a different signature, i.e.:

```
pkey = RSA.load_key("mykey.pem")
signature = pkey.private_encrypt(hashlib.sha1(text).digest(), RSA.pkcs1_padding)
print base64.b64encode(signature)  #different from the two above
```

Could you please provide some explanation? What is wrong with the latter way of signing?

Comment: Can you show your imports as well?

Comment: Sure, sorry, I added the imports

Comment: FYI, I think [pycrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) is the [preferred crypto package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137874/recommended-python-cryptographic-module) for Python these days.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the difference is that `RSA_sign` signs the digest PKCS1 algorithmIdentifier along with the digest data, where `RSA_private_encrypt` signs only the digest data.

From the **[RSA_private_encrypt](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html)** man page:

```
RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    PKCS #1 v1.5 padding. This function does not handle the
    algorithmIdentifier specified in PKCS #1. When generating or
    verifying PKCS #1 signatures, RSA_sign(3) and RSA_verify(3) should
    be used.
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens internally in `EVP.sign()` is as follows (as opposed to plain `RSA.sign()`):

```
sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1(MESSAGE).digest()
# Add ASN.1 SHA-1 OID prefix
sha1_asn1_prefix = '3021300906052b0e03021a05000414'.decode('hex')
asn1_hash = sha1_asn1_prefix + sha1_hash
rsa = RSA.load_key(KEY)
# Use PKCS#1 padding
signature = rsa.private_encrypt(asn1_hash, RSA.pkcs1_padding).encode('hex')
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16264508/258772) for longer explanation and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrts/ccc79fc3c04ef4b8fea7) for a full example.

But the bottom line is that `EVP.sign()` should be used instead as in *code 1* above - it does the right thing internally.