# Trying to verify SHA1 message signature using Python. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, cryptography, m2crypto

I'm attempting to verify the SHA1 signature of a message by downloading a certificate from a website and extracting its public key.  There's a few bits of sample code elsewhere on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544433/how-do-you-verify-an-rsa-sha1-signature-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663084/m2crypto-signature-algorithm)), however I haven't yet figured out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import requests
from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP, X509

def verify_message(cert_url, msg, sig):
    cert_text = requests.get(cert_url, verify=True)
    cert = X509.load_cert_string(cert_text.content)
    pubkey = cert.get_pubkey()
    sig = sig.decode('base64')

    # Write a few files to disk for debugging purposes
    f = open("sig", "wb")
    f.write(sig)
    f.close()

    f = open("msg", "w")
    f.write(msg)
    f.close()

    f = open("mypubkey.pem", "w")
    f.write(pubkey.get_rsa().as_pem())
    f.close()

    pubkey.reset_context(md='sha1')
    pubkey.verify_init()
    pubkey.verify_update(msg)
    assert pubkey.verify_final(sig) == 1
```

This gives me the following assertion error:

```
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 71, in verify_message
    assert pubkey.verify_final(sig) == 1
AssertionError
```

However, if I use `openssl` from the command line along with the files generated from the above Python script, it works fine:

```
[jamie@test5 tmp]$ openssl dgst -sha1 -verify mypubkey.pem -signature sig msg
Verified OK
```

I've hit a brick wall here; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: why do you believe you need to base64 decode the signature?

Comment: @GregS Thanks for the reply.  The signature is transmitted via a HTTP POST along with the message itself; it's base64 encoded when I get it.  I omitted that step for clarity.

Comment: This works fine for me on Ubuntu with openssl 1.0.1 and m2crypto 0.21.1.  What versions are you working with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is work properly — https://gist.github.com/kalloc/5106808 
I see something else wrong here

Answer (score 1):

This code is working perfectly fine at my end.