# password encryption on python?

Tags: python, django-templates, mezzanine

I just create a new aplication in python for registration.
I save all the fields in database and user created successfully but the password is save same as it is we filled at the time of registration.
How do I encrypt or use default functonality of python for password.

Please suggest me?

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt passwords, you should hash them. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: read this: http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf

Answer (score 2):

To make offline password cracking more expensive, you could use [bcrypt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt/).

If you are limited to the stdlib, there is [`crypt` module on Unix](http://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt):

```
hashed = crypt.crypt(plaintext)
```

Comment: +1 bcrypt is the best option. In Django (which is what I suspect the author is using, based on his tags), this is called [`django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/)

Answer (score 1):

you should hash the passwords, the following code hashes the raw-input password according to your PASSWORD_HASHERS in settings.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
pass = make_password(raw_pass) # hashing is done here
user.set_password(pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't implement such stuff yourself or you likely will do it wrong.

For password storage, using some reversible encoding or symetric encryption or a simple hash from hashlib or even a randomly salted hash are all major FAILURES nowadays.

If you are using django, use some strong algorithm provided by django (usually one of: bcrypt, pbkdf2, sha512_crypt).

When not using django: use passlib - after reading its documentation.

http://code.google.com/p/passlib/

Answer (score 0):

Hash the password upon getting it from the user (and on registration) to encrypt it.

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update("My users' password here")
m.digest()
```

Ref: http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib

Answer (score 0):

For actual encryption, you can try [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) or [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/). Those are probably what you are looking for; however, there are other ways to obfuscate your passwords for the *average* user:

(if you would like to read some more answers as to what encryption method might suit you best, check out this somewhat related SO post: [Recommended Python cryptographic module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137874/recommended-python-cryptographic-module)

[hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) will provide various hash algorithms (ex. "SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512"). A simple example:

```
import hashlib
enc = hashlib.md5()
enc.update("Somerandompassword")
print enc.hexdigest()
```

And this will print you the md5 "Somerandompassword":
`c5532f9e756b4583db4c627c8aa7d303`

However, for (base64) *encoding*, for example, try:

```
import base64
enc = base64.b64encode("Somerandompassword")
```

and *decoding*

```
dec = base64.b64decode("U29tZXJhbmRvbXBhc3N3b3Jk")
print dec
```

will print: `Somerandompassword`

Comment: md5 is not an encryption method, but a hash method. And it can't be decrypted (which is the whole point). Other than that, md5 is not really suited for password hashing anymore, use something stronger for that.

Comment: That's a very good point. You're definitely correct on that one. My fault.

Comment: base64 is not encryption, it's an encoding method. It's just as bad as plain text (everybody can decode it).

Comment: If I am using hash then error comes "500 internal serve"...But now I found the solution..You just need to use this.. value.set_password("your password variable or password")